# Use sed or awk - or other text processor - to find/replace a number in a range

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I'm a beginner with regular expressions and processing text. What I need to do is format the text in a file into CSV format to import into a spreadsheet.

I need to find a number with a certain range and insert a carriage return - `\r` - after it and remove a comma. I know how to find/replace for specific characters, but not in a range of characters or numbers.

This is the deal: I have a long text file, in this format.

```
Shimshon A
(blank)
November 24, 2012
13,481
jonathan t
Laguna Niguel, CA
November 24, 2012
13,480
scott b
Sussex, NJ
November 24, 2012
13,479
```

I've added end of line commas and beginning/end of line quote marks in a text editor with find/replace:

```
"Shimshon A",
"(blank)",
"November 24, 2012",
"13,481",
"jonathan t",
"Laguna Niguel, CA",
"November 24, 2012",
"13,480",
"scott b",
"Sussex, NJ",
"November 24, 2012",
"13,479",
```

But once after I remove all returns, I need to insert a return after the number in the range 13,481 to 1. That's because each column in the CSV needs to be Name, Location, Date and Number, like this:

```
"Shimshon A","(blank)","November 24, 2012","13,481"
"jonathan t","Laguna Niguel, CA","November 24, 2012","13,480"
"scott b","Sussex, NJ","November 24, 2012","13,479"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another way to approach this problem is to consider your dataset as groups of four lines

**Using `awk`:**

```
awk 'NR%4!=0 { printf "%s", $0; next } { sub(/,$/,"") }1' file
```

Results:

```
"Shimshon A","(blank)","November 24, 2012","13,481"
"jonathan t","Laguna Niguel, CA","November 24, 2012","13,480"
"scott b","Sussex, NJ","November 24, 2012","13,479"
```

Explanation:

As you can see, this uses the [modulus operator](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-6) to 'grep' every line that is not *exactly* divisible by four (i.e. not an integer). The 'printf' statement prints these lines alongside each other. 'next' skips when successful. At all other times the lagging comma is removed, and the line is printed (the 1 at the end of the statement is shorthand to print by default). Any question, please feel free to ask. HTH.

You could have also integrated the adding of commas and double quotes, by simply changing the `printf` statement:

```
awk 'NR%4!=0 { printf "\"%s\",", $0; next } { printf "\"%s\"\n", $0 }' file
```

---

**Using `GNU sed`:**

```
sed -n 'N;N;N;s/\n\|,$//g;p' file
```

Or prior to the addition of the commas and double quotes:

```
sed -n 'N;N;N;s/^\|$/"/g;s/\n/","/g;p' file
```

Results:

```
"Shimshon A","(blank)","November 24, 2012","13,481"
"jonathan t","Laguna Niguel, CA","November 24, 2012","13,480"
"scott b","Sussex, NJ","November 24, 2012","13,479"
```

Explanation:

Although this solution is much shorter, it has the same sentiment as described using `awk`, above. For the first `sed` statement: disable default printing with the `-n` flag. Append three lines to pattern space. On the fourth line, remove newline characters and lagging commas. Then print.

The second `sed` statement is much the same; append three lines to pattern space. On the fourth line, replace the start and ends of the line with double quotes. Also replace newline characters with double quote, comma, double quote; globally. Then print. HTH.

---

**From the comments:**

From my experience sorting using `awk` (although possible) can become difficult to read rather quickly. Here's a way that lets you re-use some of the previous code we've written using two other tools, `paste` and `sort`:

```
paste <(awk -F, 'NR%4==2 { print $NF }' file) <(awk 'NR%4!=0 { printf "\"%s\",", $0; next } { printf "\"%s\"\n", $0 }' file) | sort | sed 's/[^"]*//'
```

It should be noted that this command uses input prior to the addition of commas and double quotes -- As you can see it uses the second `awk` command described above. It works by pasting (with `paste`) the 'state' ahead of each of the results we obtained earlier. This then allows the line to be alphabetically sorted using `sort`. Once the input has been sorted, `sed` is used to strip off this info.

Comment: Finished editing. Hopefully not too many typos. Comments welcome.

Comment: Also, see this link - you may find it insightful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550072/awk-insert-a-new-row-after-the-regular-expression/13550483#13550483

Comment: Thanks for all the work; I'm learning from the examples. The awk examples work fine, and I figured out how to read from one file and output to another file, i.e. file.txt > newfile.txt. The sed examples don't want to work; the first doesn't change the text (on standard output) and the second, while it processes everything, for some reason it strips the first and last quote marks on each line. Might be the sed I'm using on OS X; it seems to be POSIX sed and not GNU sed. But, awk works fine, and thats fine with me. Thanks.

Comment: And now I realize that I need to split one of the lines - the city and state line - into two lines in order to be able to sort on the state. Let me see if I can figure that out, using the line counting technique. It's every four lines, but offset by 1 at the beginning. Some of those lines are (blank), while others are half blank, i.e. ` , AZ`

Comment: @songdogtech: Yes you're right. I should have mentioned that the `sed` commands are GNU only, unfortunately. I've also updated my answer to help you sort the lines by 'state'. HTH.

Comment: Do not do `printf $0` in awk as that will mess up badly if your input contains any printf formatting characters. the synposis for printf is `printf fmt, data` so you should use `printf "%s",$0`

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks Ed, I think I've developed some bad habits. Fixed.