# Awk - insert a new row after the regular expression?

Tags: regex, awk

File contents: (based on topic -> [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547392/use-sed-or-awk-or-other-text-processor-to-find-replace-a-number-in-a-range))

```
"Shimshon A",
"(blank)",
"November 24, 2012",
"13,481",
"jonathan t",
"Laguna Niguel, CA",
"November 24, 2012",
"13,480",
"scott b",
"Sussex, NJ",
"November 24, 2012",
"13,479",
```

How to improve the command?:

```
gawk --posix 'ORS="";{sub(/,[0-9]{3}/, "&&\n"); print }' file
```

Result:

```
$ gawk --posix 'ORS="";{sub(/,[0-9]{3}/, "&&\n"); print }' file
"Shimshon A","(blank)","November 24, 2012","13,481,481
","jonathan t","Laguna Niguel, CA","November 24, 2012","13,480,480
","scott b","Sussex, NJ","November 24, 2012","13,479,479
",userpc@userpc-desktop:~/Pulpit$
```

I want to print:

```
"Shimshon A","(blank)","November 24, 2012","13,481"
"jonathan t","Laguna Niguel, CA","November 24, 2012","13,480"
"scott b","Sussex, NJ","November 24, 2012","13,479"
```

Please only solution in awk.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you don't want to duplicate the last 3 digits of the number, why do you have that in your `sub()` function? The other question seems to show how to do everything you want, what's wrong with it?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13547392/use-sed-or-awk-or-other-text-processor-to-find-replace-a-number-in-a-range/13547947#13547947

Comment: @steve, I know those solutions, but I want to do it my way.

Comment: @Barmar, because I wanted to replace the last 3 digits and print a new line.

Comment: When you write `&&` it means you want to __duplicate__ the last 3 digits, since each `&` will be replaced with the match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
awk -v ORS="" '/"[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}"/ { sub(/,$/,""); print $0 "\n"; next }1' file
```

Results:

```
"Shimshon A","(blank)","November 24, 2012","13,481"
"jonathan t","Laguna Niguel, CA","November 24, 2012","13,480"
"scott b","Sussex, NJ","November 24, 2012","13,479"
```

Comment: What will happen if the date is November 13?

Comment: Yes, Fixed. But I don't think the question has anything to do with regex

Comment: @steve, Thank you for a good solution. 
Your solution works, but you have to add the `--posix` --> `awk --posix -v ORS="" '/"[0-9]{2},[0-9]{3}"/ { sub(/,$/,""); print $0 "\n"; next }1' file`
It's a shorter solution will work -> `awk --posix -v ORS="" '/,[0-9]{3}/{ sub(/,$/,""); print $0 "\n"; next }1' file`.

Comment: You're adding --posix to get RE-intervals to work. That functionality is enabled by default in newer gawk versions (check the manuals for which) so you don't need it there and in older gawk versions you should use --re-interval instead of --posix so you don't disable all gawk extenisons like gensub() and time functions.

Answer (score 1):

This one liner will work,

```
awk -FS="" 'BEGIN{ORS=""} {print substr($1, 1, length($1)-1) ((c%4==3)? "\n": ",");c=c+1;}' file
```

Here is a more elaborated version.

```
awk -FS="" 'BEGIN{
    ORS="";
    c=0
} {
    print substr($1, 1, length($1)-1) ((c%4==3)? "\n": ",");
    c=c+1;
}' < file
```

Answer (score 1):

I know you said only awk. If you're willing to stretch:

```
paste -d "" - - - - < file | sed 's/,$//'
```